# What's the easiest way to simulate looped user input on a mac?

Tags: mac

I need to simulate user activity on Mac OS for some testing purposes. Does anyone have any recommendations on how this could be achieved? An ideal solution would be one that allows me to record a set of inputs (mouse moving/click, text entry as well as other keyboard input) and 'play' through them on repeat.

Answer (score 0):

A likely solution is called [SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/), but it involves some simple scripting and is not "point and click" stupidly easy to use.

I should caveat that it's been a few years since I last futzed with it, but it appears to still be under active development.